# Detect mouse movement if Cursor is locked

Tags: c#, winforms, cad

I am developing Cad application and want to implement snap - when user moves mouse near some object, I set Cursor.Position to the center point of that object. If user moves mouse say 7 pixels in any direction, then Cursor is set free.The way I do it is - I store snaped Cursor position and then under MouseMoveEvent I calculate the distance from stored position to current position. If this position is smaller than defined threshold then I set current cursor position back to stored value. Every time MouseMoveEvent is called that small difference between two cursor positions is added to previously calclated difference, so sooner or later my threshold is reached and Cursor jumps out of snaped position. Code sample:

```
   var x = Cursor.Position.X - storedPosition.X;
   pixelsX += x;

   int threshold = 7;
   if (pixelsX > threshold)
   {
          Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(storedPosition.X + 10, storedPosition.Y);
          snapReleased = true;
   }
```

The problem with this is that in every MouseMoveEvent mouse is moved very small amount and if threshold is not reached it is set back to stored position which makes Cursor blink(which is very annoying) So my question is - is there a way to detect mouse movement if Cursor is locked in one position?

Comment: Perhaps a nicer UI would be to highlight the centre point (eg by drawing a small filled circle) when the cursor is near enough to the object, and unhighlight it if the cursor moves away.

Comment: @ Matthew Yes, I have already done it, but it is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a custom panel control that demonstrates an owner drawn cursor that snaps to a grid (`snapPoints`).  The system cursor is hidden/shown on mouse entry/leave.  The snap to point distance is controlled by the constant `snapLimit`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {

    public class DrawingSurface : Panel
        {
        private const double snapLimit = 7.0D;
        private List<Point> snapPoints = new List<Point>();
        private Point cursorPos;
        private Point lastDrawnPos;
        private bool drawCursor;

        public DrawingSurface() : base()
            {
            this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            this.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
            }

        protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
            {
            base.OnMouseEnter(e);
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Hide();
            }

        protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
            {
            base.OnMouseLeave(e);
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Show();
            this.drawCursor = false;
            this.Invalidate();
            }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
            {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            foreach (Point dot in this.snapPoints)
                {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, dot.X - 1, dot.Y - 1, 2, 2);
                }
            if (drawCursor)
                {
                Cursor cur = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current;
                Point pt = this.cursorPos;
                pt.Offset(-cur.HotSpot.X, -cur.HotSpot.Y);
                Rectangle target = new Rectangle(pt, cur.Size);
                cur.Draw(e.Graphics, target);
                this.lastDrawnPos = this.cursorPos;
                }

            }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
            {
            base.OnMouseMove(e);
            SetCursor(e.Location);
            }

        private void SetCursor(Point loc)
            {
            this.cursorPos = loc;
            foreach (Point pt in this.snapPoints)
                {
                double deltaX = loc.X - pt.X;
                double deltaY = loc.Y - pt.Y;
                double radius = Math.Sqrt((deltaX * deltaX) + (deltaY * deltaY));
                if (radius < snapLimit)
                    {
                    this.cursorPos = pt;
                    break;
                    }
                }
            if (lastDrawnPos != this.cursorPos)
                {
                this.drawCursor = true;
                this.Invalidate();
                }
            }

        protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
            {
            base.OnSizeChanged(e);
            this.snapPoints.Clear();
            for (int y = 0; y <= this.ClientRectangle.Height; y += 50)
                {
                for (int x = 0; x <= this.ClientRectangle.Width; x += 50)
                    {
                    this.snapPoints.Add(new Point(x, y));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would not "snap" the mouse pointer. Do you know the feeling when your mouse is stuck? Depending on your age you may remember roller mice, those with a rubber ball inside. It is horrible.

Instead, I think that the objects you are about to select or are currently moving should react with a snap. For example, when you are about to select an object, when the mouse pointer is closer than the threshold the object gets highlighted. The user can the click the mouse and grab the object.

When moving an object, the object can snap into place when closer than the threshold to another object, guide lines, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is exactly what I want - stuck mouse, which gets released if I move mouse some distance away. This is the default way how snap works in all AutoCad applications.